# Add marker on highchart

Tags: highcharts

How to add  markers at particular points (x,y) in high-chart line graph?

I have tried this:-

```
marker: {
            symbol: 'square'
        }
```

Am adding x and y values as dynamic array.I need to iterate the array in a loop and plot markers manually at certain points .Is it possible?

Comment: Could you post a live example, like jsFiddle? Marker setting can be passed in data - [example1](http://jsfiddle.net/v5j69unq/). If you want to change points dynamically, then you could use [`Point.update()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update). Another way might be to add a scatter series for markers - [example2](http://jsfiddle.net/v5j69unq/1/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably the best way to do it is to add a data series that represents the marker, so it would be something like this (pseudo-code):

`var myMarkerPosition = myValueFromArray;
    mychart.addSeries(myMarkerPosition);`

and you can then do something like: 
`mychart.series[1].update({ symbol: square });`

later on if you want to. Don't forget to replace your marker if you want to move it to another position by updating it.